# laravel post does not get picked up?

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes

I am trying to pass a form through. I am using request method to get variables. here is my blade of a form:

```
<div class="add_photo">
<h1>Add a photo</h1>
    <form action="{{Route('postPhoto')}}">
        <span>Name: </span>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <span>File: </span>
        <input type="text" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
    </form>
</div>
```

Routes involved:

```
Route::get('/admin/gallery', 'GalleryController@manageGallery')->name('manageGallery');
Route::post('/admin/gallery', 'GalleryController@postPhoto')->name('postPhoto');
```

And this is my controller for it:

```
  class GalleryController extends Controller
{
    public function manageGallery() {
        return view('home.manageGallery');
    }

    public function postPhoto(Request $request) {
        die("works");
    }
}
```

It does not throw error at me. It just does nothing. So my question is: am I using this method wrong or do I need something more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see what you are expecting this to do. Have you tried `dd($request)` inside `postPhoto()`

Comment: I did. and it does not return anything.

Comment: I would like to see that the postPhoto() gets the variables posted. Sorry for double comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make sure that the form you are using is using the correct method for your route

```
<div class="add_photo">
   <h1>Add a photo</h1>
   <form action="{{Route('postPhoto')}}" method="post">
        <span>Name: </span>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <span>File: </span>
        <input type="text" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
    </form>
</div>
```

In your controller, put the following in the `postPhoto` function

```
public function postPhoto(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

You should now get a `Request` object output to the screen when you submit the form

Comment: Thank you. my actual problem was a simple one. I didn't specify the method.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna use [Blade Forms](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html) in order to make Forms in a more natural way for Laravel

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => '/admin/gallery', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) }}

    {{ Form::text('title') }}

    {{ Form::label('title', 'Name :') }}

    {{ Form::file('file') }}

    {{ Form::label('file', 'File :') }}

    {{ Form::submit('Add') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

It reduces the overhead of adding the token by yourself as it is automatically added when using the Form facade.

And then, in your controller, you would do something like that to debug when sending the form :

```
<?php

use Request; /* do not forget this line */

class GalleryController extends Controller
{
    public function postPhoto(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->toArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: tahnks. I will have to look into it.